# Arrange matplotlib data to have strings on one of the axis instead than integer (not a label)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Scenario: I have data retrieved per machine; imagine cameras, and I do some tests, like taking photo, take a burst and so on, saving these values.

I would like to use matplotlib to graph the data, but I can't find a way to get the data on one of the axis, so I can associate the name of the camera with the various parameters.

So far I can plot the data correctly; so if I have 3 parameters (time to take a photo, time to recharge the flash and max number of shots in burst), I can plot them like this:

```
camera1 = (0.4, 0.74, 8)
camera2 = (0.32, 0.2, 10)
camera3 = (0.45, 1.2, 7)
camera4 = (0.6, 0.93, 5)

# programmatically create the datasets
takeshot = (0.4,0.32,0.45,0.6)
chargeflash = (0.74, 0.2, 1.2, 0.93)
burstmax = (8,10,7,5)

plt.plot(takeshot, label="Take Shot")
plt.plot(chargeflash, label="Charge Flash")
plt.plot(burstmax, label="Burst Max")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

What I get though, is on one axis the values, which is fine; and on the other, I get the number of values (so from 0 to 4).
I would like to get on that axis, the names of the cameras, so when I look at the data, I can see that camera 2 is the fastest to take a shot, compared to the other cameras, and so on.

I was not able to find a way to tell matplotlib to do so; the camera name is a string, and if I use a list of strings for the axis, I get an exception.

EDIT: Not a duplicate; I do not have common values that I want to put on the X axis, from the Y axis; mine are all unique values, the scope is different, even if the final purpose (put text on the X axis) is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you want labels? Is this the result you are looking for?
[image]
With labels it "seems" there are strings on the x axis.

I also scaled all the relative values (and hided the y labels) in order to have more visibility. To do that, I was forced to plot arrays and not lists.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

camera1 = (0.4, 0.74, 8)
camera2 = (0.32, 0.2, 10)
camera3 = (0.45, 1.2, 7)
camera4 = (0.6, 0.93, 5)

# programmatically create the datasets
takeshot = np.array([0.4,0.32,0.45,0.6])
chargeflash = np.array([0.74, 0.2, 1.2, 0.93])
burstmax = np.array([8, 10, 7, 5])

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
labels = ['CAM1', 'CAM2', 'CAM3', 'CAM4']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='horizontal')
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.plot(x, takeshot*2, label="Take Shot")
plt.plot(x, chargeflash, label="Charge Flash")
plt.plot(x, burstmax/3, label="Burst Max")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes this is what I was trying to achieve, but I did find only labels for the axis, which would print once and not at every tick, which is why I did mention that I didn't want the label.